# -- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so (Required is exact version "3.6.3")

Tags: software-installation, compiling, python3

I'm trying to compile [Shogun-toolbox](https://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun/wiki/README_cmake) from source... I could compiled it before, everything alright, but cmake detect python 2.7 as default (because Ubuntu does) and I can't use that library in python3.6

As said in the link I put before, in order to compile shogun to be used in python 3 I have to specify that I'm using python 3 using cmake in this way:

```
cmake -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.3 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/python3 -DPYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages -DPythonModular=ON ..
```

But, then I do that I got this in the cmake output:

```
Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so (Required is exact version "3.6.3")
```

while I should get something like this (what do I get when using python2):

```
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (found suitable exact version "2.7.14")
```

I've thought that maybe I have not exactly libpython 3.6.3 installed but, when I execute

```
sudo apt-get install libpython3.6
```

I get this output:

```
libpython3.6 is already the newest version (3.6.3-1ubuntu1).
```

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.

If I try to make shogun without solve this issue I got:

```
[ 54%] Building CXX object src/interfaces/python/CMakeFiles/_interface_python.dir/shogunPYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
/home/grg121/code/shogun/build/src/interfaces/python

/shogunPYTHON_wrap.cxx:175:11: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 # include <Python.h>

       ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
src/interfaces/python/CMakeFiles/_interface_python.dir/build.make:73: recipe for target 'src/interfaces/python/CMakeFiles/_interface_python.dir/shogunPYTHON_wrap.cxx.o' failed
make[2]: *** [src/interfaces/python/CMakeFiles/_interface_python.dir/shogunPYTHON_wrap.cxx.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1219: recipe for target 'src/interfaces/python/CMakeFiles/_interface_python.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/interfaces/python/CMakeFiles/_interface_python.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:162: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Python.h is not found but... If I execute

```
locate Python.h
```

I get:

```
/usr/include/python2.7/Python.h
/usr/include/python3.6m/Python.h
```

And I'm executing cmake with:

```
cmake -DINTERFACE_PYTHON=ON BUILD_META_EXAMPLES=ON -DENABLE_TESTING=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DBUILD_DASHBOARD_REPORTS=ON -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3.6 -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/Python3.6m -DPYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages ..
```

So... I can't understand what's happen.

Someone have an idea of what's happen?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

OK. I have made it work....

After re_reading [that readme](https://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun/wiki/README_cmake) I saw that I wasn't putting "PA in DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE

I'm not sure why it works if do that but, executing cmake in this way:

```
cmake -DINTERFACE_PYTHON=ON BUILD_META_EXAMPLES=ON -DENABLE_TESTING=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DBUILD_DASHBOARD_REPORTS=ON DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.6m -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/python3.6 -DPYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages ..
```

I finally got it working.